# CGridviews are Adding newly on search

Tags: yii, yii-components

I created 4 different widgets using the YII Framework, each of which contains a one-by-one `CGridview`. I am showing all 4 widgets in one view. The problem is that when I am searching in one `CGridview`, it's giving the search results in 3 new `CGridview`s.

Before Search it looks like this:

[image: Before Search it's look like :]

After Search it looks like this:

[image: After Search it's look like :]

Comment: A vague question would make visitors to ignore it right away. The screen shot was still small and doesn't make sense. Since the people could not recognize what you expect, what you don't, the problem has been described less detail for us to understand your point. Someone could help once your question is improved

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you assign the same ID to all of the CGridView widgets.

```
$this->widget('ext.MyGridView.MyGridView', array(
'id'=>'unique-ID',
...
```

Make sure the IDs are different.